# Excel Macro for check mark to add a string at the end of an existing string for select cells in a row

Tags: vba, excel

I'm wondering how I can create, in VBA, a macro with a ActiveX Control Checkmark to add a string at the end of an existing string for select cells in Excel

I have a table of teachers with all the associated classes they teach, and I want a checkbox that I can select if they're bilingual.  In the event they're bilingual, adding a string to the course name allows me to then use a CountIF function to find how many classes are taught in each of two languages.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you need with Excel functions. 
First of all activate de Developer ribbon (Rigth click on ribbon -> Customize ribbon -> Check Developer tab). 
Then in the developer tab, click on insert -> Checkbox. Put the checkbox wherever you want, then right click on it and select Format Control -> Control, and set the cell which will hold the status of the checkbox, in "cell link".
Now that cell will hold the values TRUE/FALSE, so with an IF() function you can CONCATENATE() a suffix or do whatever you want.